# Having trouble printing a value on the same row in google script (clock-in/out system)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the idea of my spreadsheet:
I want to create a spreadsheet that will let me click a button to clock in and another button to clock out. I am the only user, so no need for multi-user functionality. I want to be able to clock in (for example at 12:00pm) and clock out at separate times (for example, 6:00pm) My problem is that whenever I want to clock out, it will record the clock out time on the next column. How can I make it to where it will record the clock out time on the same row as the clock in time?

Here's my code:

```
function setValue(cellName, value){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}
function getNextRow(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}
 
function addStart(a, b, c, d){
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a); // employee name row
  setValue('B' + row, b); // date row
  setValue('C' + row, c); // clock in time row
  setValue('D' + row, d); // clock out time row
}

function punchIn(){
  var dd = new Date();
  var currentTime = dd.toLocaleTimeString();
  addStart("Employee1", new Date(), currentTime, "")
}
function punchOut(){
  var dd = new Date();
  var currentTime = dd.toLocaleTimeString(); 
  addStart("","","",currentTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both `punchIn` and `punchOut` use the `getNextRow` function, thus the out will be a row after the in.

Following the presented pattern, you are "missing" the functions `getCurrentRow` and `addEnd` for the `punchOut` function.  Here they are added in:

```js
function setValue(cellName, value){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}
function getNextRow(){
  return getCurrentRow() + 1;
}
function getCurrentRow(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow();
}
function addStart(a, b, c, d){
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a); // employee name row
  setValue('B' + row, b); // date row
  setValue('C' + row, c); // clock in time row
  setValue('D' + row, d); // clock out time row
}
function addEnd(endTime) {
  var row = getCurrentRow();
  setValue('D' + row, endTime);
}
function punchIn(){
  var dd = new Date();
  var currentTime = dd.toLocaleTimeString();
  addStart("Employee1", new Date(), currentTime, "")
}
function punchOut(){
  var dd = new Date();
  var currentTime = dd.toLocaleTimeString(); 
  addEnd(currentTime);
}
```